# Нарисовать все строки массива на канвасе

Tags: android, canvas, массивы

Вот код, рисуется только текущее значение массива, соответственно, рисуясь все ниже, а предыдущие строки не сохраняются, а после прохода через весь массив всё нарисованное пропадает. Необходимо, чтобы отобразились **все строки  массива на канвасе** и не исчезали.

```
if
 (count<mz.length-1)
{
count++;
fy+=20;
}

for (int i = 0; i < mz.length-1; i++) {

       kraska1.setColor(Color.WHITE);
       holst.drawText(mz[count], 10,10+fy, kraska1);

    }
```